Finding $x^2 + y^2$ With No Intermediate Variables
I've recently been trying out assembly code and I was wondering if the equation $x^2 + y^2$ could be calculated one operation at a time with no intermediate variables.
For example, this equation can be calculated like so:
result = x * x
temp = y * y
result += temp

This requires an intermediate variable 'temp'. I was very curious if this equation could be done with no intermediate variables. No, I am not asking this for practical purposes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you're only doing one operation at a time then you'll need to store the values as you go. No way around it.

@CyclotomicField I am not asking this for practical reasons, I won't actually be using this for assembly. Surely there is some way to do it?

It's impossible for a binary operation. You need to compute the data before you can use it in the next function. Even when you write $x^2+y^2$ the computer is storing temporary values during the evaluation.

This is math.se not stackoverflow. If this is truly a programming question where it is important to know details of assembly, I think you should ask it at SO. If you want to ask it here, assume readers do not know details of assembly and explain in your question more parameters. For example, are you only allowed one arithmetic operation at a time? Must each operation be one of the four most basic operations? Is looping permitted?

result = x * x
result /= y
result += y
result *= y

If it is possible that $y=0$ you could insert a branch point to skip the steps after the first multiplication if $y$ is zero.

If you don't need to preserve the previous values of x and y,
x *= x
y *= y
x += y

Then the result will be stored in x and you don't need a third register/memory location.

If you have access to trig functions and $x>0$:
r = y/x
r = arctan(r)
r = cos(r)
r = x/r
r = r*r


I see, so there isn't actually a way to do it with binary operations. Trig functions require temporary variables after all. Thank you, this is very insightful!

Some modern hardware can directly execute trig functions and then there would be no need for the software to use temporary variables. Although, I don't know about inverse trig functions.
